# Want to change the CSS when the bottom of a fixed div reaches the top of the footer div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a fixed position div that I want to turn into absolute positioning when it reaches the top of the footer so basically it looks like the div stops when it hits the footer.

#### CSS

```
#body {
    width:100%;
    height:800px;
    position:relative;
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background-color:yellow;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#arrow {
    position:fixed;
    width:20px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:black;
    top:160px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
function scroll_style() {
    var window_top = $('#arrow').offset().top;
    var div_top = $('#footer').offset().top;

    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#arrow').css({position:'absolute',bottom:0,top:"auto"});
    }
}
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(scroll_style);
    scroll_style();
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/be2Ff/1/. it works when the top of #arrow reaches the top of #footer but I need it to change when the bottom of the #arrow reaches the footer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to account for the height of the arrow. Just add:

```
var window_top = $('#arrow').offset().top + $('#arrow').height();
```

to your function.

Answer (score 2):

### [See this working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/be2Ff/3/)

All you need to do is add the `#arrow`'s height to its position. At this point, you may want to cache the arrow's jQuery object first.

```
var $arrow = $('#arrow'),
    window_top = $arrow.offset().top + $arrow.outerHeight(),
    div_top = $('#footer').offset().top;
```